# Is it safe to use same reCaptcha v3 Token for multiple requests?

Tags: php, recaptcha, captcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

I have an upload form with reCaptcha v3 in PHP with DropzoneJS. I am uploading 10 files with 10 different Post requests. When a User uploads 10 files, the client gets 10 different Captcha Tokens in a few milliseconds. The Server then timeouts because he has to check 10 different Tokens within some very short time.

Would it still be safe **if the user would get the reCaptcha Token only on the first post request**? The Captcha State would be saved in the user Session and if it's valid, the client would not have to get 9 more Captcha tokens.

Like: (logic code)

```
if Captcha is valid: $SESSION['captcha'] = 'valid';

if files_ammount > 10 = getNewCaptchaToken();
```